# Lucene.NET through NHibernate.Search and POCO Entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lucene.net, poco, nhibernate.search

Is there anyway to keep true POCO Entities while working with Lucene.NET through NHibernate.Search ?

It seems that Lucene.NET (NHibernate.Search) mapping only work with Attributes within Entity classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was true, not too long ago. However, there are different mapping providers out there. Take a look into the source code for the Mapping namespace. You will have to build your own provider but it is possible.

Comment: @Andrew: I took a look on the mapping namespace but ... don't know how to build my own provider and get it working with NHibernate.Search